# Issue with Laravel 5.8 kernel class

Tags: laravel

running
`php artisan serve`

> PHP Fatal error:  Type of App\Http\Kernel::$middlewareGroups must not be defined (as in class Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project-api/app/Http/Kernel.php on line 7

My package.json

```
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.4.1",
        "ext-json": "*",
        "barryvdh/laravel-cors": "^0.11.2",
        "beyondcode/laravel-websockets": "^1.4",
        "cboden/ratchet": "^0.4.2",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "get-stream/stream-laravel": "~2.2.6",
        "intervention/image": "^2.5",
        "kreait/firebase-php": "^4.18",
        "laravel/framework": "6.0.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "laravel/ui": "^2.2",
        "nesbot/carbon": "^2.28",
        "spatie/laravel-image-optimizer": "^1.5",
        "tymon/jwt-auth": "^1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.2",
        "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0"
    },
```

and Http\Kernel.php

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\ModifyViewFolder::class,
    ];
```

MiddlewareGroup

```
    protected array $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
            \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
        ],
    ];
```

Tried deleting and reinstall all packages and that's when this issue started when i was trying to upgrade to Laravel 7.*

Comment: show the `$middlewareGroups` array

Comment: @lagbox Updated.

Comment: the error is very clear ... you can't define a type for that variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove keyword "array" from `protected array $middlewareGroups = [`. Should be: `protected $middlewareGroups = [`. Your IDE probably added this type declaration.